# Events and notifications in BACnet4J

Tags: events, notifications, bacnet, bacnet4j

I am using BACnet4J for a BACnet device simulator. I get it to create objects and react to reads and writes to properties. I have also played with COVSubscriptions. Everything works fine.
Now I want to use events when a state of a Binary Input changes.
Is there no automatic way of triggering events?
From how I understand the code I thought I am supposed to do the following:

- set up a binary input object
- set up a notification class object
- set the notification class property for binary input to match the notification class object id

Now I was expecting BACnet4J to trigger events whenever the present value of the binary input changes, but it doesn't.
I found a method i LocalDevice which looks quite suitable. It is called sendIntrinsicEvent(...), but there is no call to that method.

Do I have to call that method on my own, whenever the state changes?

Comment: Do you have documentation for what you're trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, yes, there is no automatic notification. 
We had to implement on value change an event notification using the method you have already found (sendIntrinsicEvent).